# How to insert colons into Mac address from Postgres SELECT without any

Tags: regex, postgresql, insert

I'm trying to convert the output of a SELECT of a MAC address in a Postgres database from for example: ab12cd34ef56 to AB:12:CD:34:EF:56 and I haven't been able to find a Postgres function or Regex that will do it.

Also, the column is defined as a VARCHAR so I can't use the built in MAC network functions.

Any help would be appreciated!

I've tried many different string functions with no success...

Answer (score 3):

You can use [REGEX_REPLACE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/functions-matching.html) like so:

```
lanny=# SELECT TRIM(':' FROM REGEXP_REPLACE('ab12cd34ef56', '([a-fA-F0-9]{2})', '\1:', 'g'));
       btrim       
-------------------
 ab:12:cd:34:ef:56
(1 row)
```

The `TRIM` is necessary because this replacement on its own will produce a trailing colon.

Comment: The Regex just gives me spaces and colons.   I'm not sure if the issue is a Postgres version issue, but this server is an Aruba Clearpass appliance so I have no control over the database.

Here are the results of my tests:

`
SELECT DISTINCT
 UPPER(radius_acct.calling_station_id) AS "Mac Address",
 TRIM(':' FROM REGEXP_REPLACE(radius_acct.calling_station_id, '([a-fA-F0-9]{2})', '\1:', 'g')) AS "Mac Regex 1",
FROM radius_acct 

Mac Address,Mac Regex 1
204C0330784D, : : : : : 
`

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to get this done with substrings and concatenation:

```sql
SELECT 
  UPPER(
    CONCAT(
      SUBSTRING(mac, 1, 2), ':',
      SUBSTRING(mac, 3, 2), ':',
      SUBSTRING(mac, 5, 2), ':',
      SUBSTRING(mac, 7, 2), ':',
      SUBSTRING(mac, 9, 2), ':',
      SUBSTRING(mac, 11)
    )
  )
 FROM table
```

Explanation: We uppercase the entire result, and then we select the `mac` column (where I assume your mac address is), and then we take the string 2 parts at a time, adding a colon `:` between each part of the mac address.

The substring function behaves as follows
`SUBSTRING(value, start[, length])`

All of these functions can be found on [Postgres's String functions documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-string.html).